# Cable conduit catches water?

Tags: waterproofing, water-damage, cables, internet

Below is the picture of how the ISP cable enters my house. Just wondering where all the rain water that gets into the same conduit goes? Doesn't seem right that no measures were taken to prevent water from getting in.

[image]

Comment: It should at least have a plug or a cap on it. You are right water will go in.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to have a cap to keep out rocks, not rain.

Outdoor conduit is supposed to be full of water. That is normal and you are expected to select wires which are designed for that.

To set expectations correctly, I recommend pouring a cup of water into every outdoor conduit! It will happen anyway.

Comment: Two questions. 1. What happens when it freezes?  2. What's preventing the water from pouring out at the other end (which is lower)?

Comment: @wynne exactly. The pipe will accumulate water whether you put it there or not.  But at least now,  you're thinking about these problems.  You weren't before.